# delete database automatically after a particular date when date column is not available in database

Tags: java, mysql

I want to delete database after 31st march of any year. However i don't have date column in my database. Can u please tell the java code which will do this? 
  I have searched that i can probably use events in myql but i am not getting how to use it to suit my application. Also, is there any better option?
I have created following database:

```
CREATE TABLE `amount` (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

           `userName` VARCHAR(100),
           `DayCareAmount` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
           `HealthCareAmount` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
            `HealthClubAmount` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

           PRIMARY KEY (`userName`)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
         ) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: It is not possible, because you do not know when the record is added

Comment: You should add a column createdDate and fill it if the record is added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

alter your table to add date or year field

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype
```

update your amount fields with respect to the date 
I got the current financial year as follows

```
public int getyear( LocalDate date) {
        System.out.println(date.getYear());
        if(date.getMonthValue() < 4){
            return date.getYear() - 1;
        }
        return date.getYear();

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add year column to your database table.
CREATE TABLE `amount` (

```
       `userName` VARCHAR(100),
       `DayCareAmount` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
       `HealthCareAmount` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
       `HealthClubAmount` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
        finYr INT(4),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

       PRIMARY KEY (`userName`)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     ) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Write a logic in your servlet to check whether the date fetched from your jsp is in the particular financial year and store that year in your database table.
While fetching year, you can use where clause on finYr to get data for that particular financial year.